# Nested GridView in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, flutter-layout, nested-lists

I am trying to build a nested list using `GridView` builder in flutter. But the child list has a very small height. Since I have not specified height for any of the list, I'm not able to figure out how to increase it.

---

This is code I'm using to build the nested list.

```
    return DecoratedBox(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: Styles.scaffoldBackground,
      ),
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            _buildSearchBox(),
          Expanded(
            child:GridView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 1,
                  childAspectRatio: 3/1,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                  mainAxisSpacing:50),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                itemCount: res2.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
       
                  value: res2[index],
                  child:Column( mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children:<Widget>[

                    GestureDetector(
                    onTap: (){
                      Navigator.push(
                          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProductOverview()));

                    },
                    child: shopItem(),),
                  Expanded(
                    child:Container(
                      height: 10*_blockSizeVertical,
                    child:GridView.builder(
                    physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 1,
                          childAspectRatio: 3/1,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 20),
                     itemCount: results.length,
                       itemBuilder: (context, index) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                      value: results[index],
                        child: productItem(
                ),

              ),

            ),),),],),
                ),),),
],
      ),
    ),);
  }
```

---

Screenshot of the list:

[image: img]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `childAspectRatio` of the parent GridView. It takes width/height.

Change it to  `childAspectRatio: 3/6 ;`